# Java GWT Image.onErrorHandler is not triggering

Tags: java, image, gwt, loading

I have a image loading problem on GWT.

On server side:

- I have a HttpServlet that creates and transfers Captcha images using "https://github.com/chintanbuch/simplecaptcha".

On the client side:

- I am calling this servlet by puting a new url to a GWT Image object.

However, even I am using localhost, somethimes the image does not shown. And it never triggers "onError", always "onLoad".

[image: Screenshot of the image]

How should I debug it? Please help.

```
tbCaptcha = new TextBox();

imgCaptcha = new Image();
imgCaptcha.addErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
    public void onError(ErrorEvent event) {
        d.ce("onCaptcha", "onError", System.currentTimeMillis());
        onCaptcha.execute();
    }
});
imgCaptcha.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
    public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
        d.cr("onCaptcha", "onLoad", System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
});

var login = TGS_LibScaleServletUtils.login();
var newUrl = TGC_CaptchaUtils.newUrl(login.domain, login.port, login.spi);
imgCaptcha.setUrl(newUrl);
```

And yes, I am creating a new URL with a random parameter and using Image.prefetch as below:

```
public static String newUrl(CharSequence domain, Integer port, CharSequence spi) {
    var newUrlCaptcha = TGS_UrlBuilderUtils.https()
            .domain(domain).port(port).directory(spi)
            .fileOrServlet(TGS_SURLUtils.LOC_NAME)
            .parameter(TGS_SURLUtils.PARAM_NAME, TGS_CaptchaUtils.SERVLET_REFRESH())
            .parameterRandom("r", 10).toString();
    Image.prefetch(newUrlCaptcha);
    return newUrlCaptcha;
}
```

Client side console:

[image]

see the api code in github [github](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.api.captcha/tree/main/src/main/java/com/tugalsan/api/captcha)

Comment: can you attach console screenshot. Does it have error?

Comment: On servlet side, there is no error... I have added client side console log. only onLoad. I need to click Refresh button a few times, to create the problem. But sometimes it happens even on initilial render.

Comment: change to Light browser theme from Dark Dark Theme? Because captcha image has black colored text which matches with black background.

Comment: @RaviSamani Interestingly, i could not able to create the same problem in light theme.... I am trying hard....Hmm Maybe as u said there is a tranparency settings in the library i used for capthca and i randomly made it available... I will look on to that. Thank you

Comment: @RaviSamani Yes, I figured out that i was using random backgrounds, transparent one included. removing it from the list solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to Light browser theme from Dark Dark Theme.
As captcha image is transparent having black colored text, which matches with black background.